# Which file run before controller file

Tags: codeigniter

I have a project in CI and whenever I reload a page or go to other page it shows me `cont` on screen then load rest things. I tried to delete all views from controller but it's still showing me `cont` on every page. So where I can find it?

Here's a screen capture of it :
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by `cont`? can you show us your screen shot?

Comment: @M.Hemant i had added the screenshot please check

Comment: index.php (under application folder) run before controller file.

Answer (score 0):

In the header file maybe use the string "cont".
Please delete the part of the header file that prints the string "cont".